# Trying to understand a proof from an article

Tags: operator-theory, ideals, c-star-algebras

I'm currently reading proof of Proposition $5.2$ from the paper [The ideal structure of the Haagerup tensor product of $C^{\ast}$-algebras](https://eudml.org/doc/153553). Let $A$ be a simple $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $B$ be any $C^{\ast}$-algebra. Let $I$ be a closed ideal of $A\otimes^h B$. If $I_1$ and $I_2$ are ideals of $ B$ satisfying $M\otimes^h I_i \subseteq I$ for $i=1,2$. Then $$M\otimes^h(I_1+I_2)= M\otimes^h I_1+ M\otimes^h I_2 \subseteq I. $$ Thus

> There is a largest closed ideal $J$ of $B$ such that $A \otimes^h J \subseteq I$

I'm not able to follow this step. By applying Zorn's lemma I can see that there is a maximal element $J$ but i cannot see the existence of largest ideal. Can someone please explain.

Comment: Please try to make the subject line about the mathematics of the post, rather than your actions around it. That makes it easier for future users who perform searches to recognize the post as potentially useful without having to click to see just what, among the billions of articles in existence, you may have been struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of ideals $I'\subset B$ such that $A\otimes^h I'\subset I$.  Let
$$
J=\overline{\Big\{\sum_{\alpha\in F}x_\alpha:\ F\subset\mathcal F,\ \text{ finite}, x_\alpha\in\alpha\Big\}}\subset B.
$$
Then $J$ is an ideal of $B$ and by definition it contains all ideals $I'$ in $B$ such that $A\otimes^hI'\subset I$.

So all we need to do is to show that $A\otimes^h J\subset I$. But this follows easily from the fact that
$$
A\otimes^h J=\overline{A\otimes\Big\{\sum_{\alpha\in F}x_\alpha:\ F\subset\mathcal F,\ \text{ finite}, x_\alpha\in\alpha\Big\}}\subset I.
$$

Comment: Thanks, Martin! I was able to figure it out after getting answer from you of my last question on sum of ideals.